# Comprehensive Mathematics References/Textbooks (Like Bourbaki's Elements, or the Stacks Project)

Tags: number-theory, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, big-list

Are there any comprehensive mathematics reference/textbooks that could be considered somewhat like a modern version of Bourbaki's Elements? "Comprehensive" here could refer to a single area of mathematics, not necessarily its entirety like what Bourbaki seemed to be attempting. Also, the completed volumes of the Elements dealt more with foundational subjects like set theory ("level D", or Bourbaki density zero, as Dieudonne calls them) as opposed to "level A" subjects like algebraic geometry and number theory, which is what I'm looking for.

I'm thinking of something along the lines of the Stacks Project in algebraic geometry, or if there was some "textbook version" of the nLab (are there any?). My interests are in algebraic geometry, number theory, and some algebraic topology and differential geometry, so this is what I'm really trying to look for, but references in other areas would be welcome too, for the benefit of people who come across this question while looking for such references in their own fields.

Comment: Do you know of EGA/SGA?

Comment: Yes, and this should have been the best example of what I am looking for.  I am wondering if there are more of the same kind. Would you consider Grothendieck's later works, like Pursuing Stacks, to be as "comprehensive" as EGA/SGA? They seem to be very big as well.

Comment: I don't think Pursing Stacks is really a reference work. You seem to have named all the standard "encyclopedic" references. Maybe you would be interested in Spivak's differential geometry series. Also, nLab is basically Urs Schreiber's personal diary, so there's not going to be a textbook version of that. The best approximation would be some combination of Categories for the Working Mathematician, Higher Topos Theory, and a ton of homotopy theory. I guess all of Lurie's manuscripts (posted on his website) might interest you, too.

Comment: And let us not get swept up in abstraction and neglect to mention OEIS, or the ATLAS of finite groups.

Comment: To add to the list of nLab-type things, consider also Riehl's *Categorical Homotopy Theory*.

Comment: I have never heard of OEIS and the ATLAS of finite groups before. Thank you very much for mentioning them! And if there are any more that you know about, please feel free to add them here.